# Two regions on sphere with same area

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a regular surface in $\mathbb R^3$ homeomorphic to sphere.Let $f$ be a simple closed geodesic in $S$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the regions of $S$ which have $f$ as a common boundary. be the Let $N:S\to S^2$ the gauss maps S.Prove that $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ has the same area

I have the idea that if I can show that the  image of $f$ under gauss map is again a simple geodesic then it is done for the we can use the gauss bonnet theorem to draw the conclusion .But I have not been able to show neither simple nor geodesic.Any help ids is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Consider the situation where $A$ is isometric to a half sphere, whereas $B$ looks like the top of a mushroom.

Comment: The problem is probably correct because i have got it from do-carmo's book..problem 3 of exercise 4.5

Comment: I think it is true if $S$ is convex. But in general the example of @AmitaiYuval will make $N(B)$ larger.

Comment: even in that case how can we show that?

Comment: In that case, the Gauss map is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: how can it be shown?

Comment: what is meant by convexity of surface here?

Comment: As the differential of the Gauss map is the second fundamental form, which is nonzero on a convex surface. Thus the Gauss map is a covering of $\mathbb S^2$. (Convexity mean that the second fundamental form always has two positive eigenvalue).

Comment: but differential of the gauss map is not the second fundamental form...it is the product of two matices..as given in the book

Comment: Is it something like $g^{ij}h_{jk}$? If you are using do-carmo's book, probably you can find the definition of convex surface in the book.

Comment: Do Carmo's book has many errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Gauss-Bonnet theorem the total curvature of $S$ is given by
$$\int_S \kappa\>d\omega =4\pi\ .$$
Since $f$ is a simply closed curve on $S$ by the Jordan curve theorem  it separates $S$ into two parts $A_1$, $A_2$, both homeomorphic to a disk. Applying Gauss-Bonnet to $A_i$ we obtain
$$\int_{A_i}\kappa\>d\omega +\int_{\pm f}\kappa_g\>ds=2\pi\qquad(i=1,\>2)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature of $f$, and as $\kappa_g$ is supposed to be $\equiv0$ we don't have to bother about the $\pm$ in $(1)$.

When $\kappa\geq0$ on $S$, i.e., when $S$ is convex, the original statement follows. If $S$ is not convex (the case of a "mushroom") one would have to clarify what is meant by the "area of $N(A_i)$". If the algebraic sum of signed areas is meant it might be possible to save the claim.

Comment: I think here are implies...integral of absolute value of K....but as you said there remains the sign ambiguity

Comment: And also thanks a lot for giving the answer...@Christian Blatter